# Record Streaming Music in Android Using Webview - No Root

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, mobile-application

In my app i want to record the song that is being played on the phone. I have searched for it and found that there is no way to record internal audio in android. One possible way is to use Visualizer but it gives a very low quality audio. Is there any way I allow the user to browse and stream song in webview in my application and then record the audio somehow? I can not find any article or blog that can help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Android MediaRecorder Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#REMOTE_SUBMIX)

According to this you can get the audio stream playing the song but you need *root* permissions on the phone. You can record the song using the Mic but that results in loss of quality.

Comment: yes i know. i dont want root permission that is why i am  searching for some other workaound

Comment: AFAIK there is no such workaround apart from recording directly from mic.